# I need to get specific ids from db if these are in current and last quarter using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

[DB Table]

[image: 1]

```
SELECT b.first_name, b.last_name, a.pod_name, a.category, c.user_id, 
    SUM(IF(QUARTER(CURDATE())-1 OR (QUARTER(CURDATE())-2) AND a.user_id, 1, 0)) AS flag FROM kudos a 
    INNER JOIN users b ON a.user_id = b.id INNER JOIN users_groups c ON a.user_id = c.user_id
    INNER JOIN groups d ON c.group_id = d.id WHERE a.group_name = 'G2' AND d.id IN (7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28)
    AND QUARTER(CURDATE())-1 = a.quarter ORDER BY a.final_score+0 DESC
```

I need to get the user_ids of those users which are both in quarter 1 and 2 from table.
Tried above query but failed to get expected results.

Can someone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

if you only need user_id then you can do this :

```
select user_id
from tablename
where quarter in (1,2)
group by user_id
having count(distinct quarter) = 2
```

another way is to use window function, assuming you have one user id in each quarter:

```
select * from (
   select * , count(*) over (partition by user_id) cn 
   from tablename
   where quarter in (1,2)
) t where cn = 2
```

Comment: But I also need other fields as well. Added join with my query, it only showing one id result irrespective of others.

Comment: @MuhammadFarhan see updated answer